# ASP.NET, Webservice response as a download link for Android

Tags: c#, asp.net, android, web-services, download

Because this webservice is supposed to be consumed using an **android device**, based on what my friend had told me, he said the only way he have is to **download a file and read from there**.

This project is **not going live**, it is demonstrated on 1 computer. So the file can be saved in a C:\ folder, instead of a live server.

So right now I am trying to find a way to return a download file link, instead of the original XML format. The download link format I am looking for is **.xml**.

My web service is in this format:

I have Location.cs

```
public List<Locations> ws(string parameter)
{
List<Locations> abc = new List<Locations>();
// Over here I populate the abc list with objects.
return abc;
}
```

Comment: What's exact question ? You need a way so that instead of returning an xml file should be saved on local disk ? And you need a path to download it from a computer where there is no IIS ?

Comment: Whether to use IIS or not, it's optional. I need a way where I can let the user download a file instead of displaying the response in XML format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as ASp.NET and C# part is concered you can do something like this .

Whenever you have file data you should write it to file . And than just call this function passing path and file name you want to appear to other end .

```
//Forces Download/Save rather than opening in Browser//
  public static void ForceDownload(string virtualPath, string fileName)
  { 

    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.WriteFile(virtualPath);
    Response.ContentType = "";
    Response.End(); 

  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. May I know where should I place this? and when should I invoke this method?

Comment: Hmm, ok, assuming my web service is as follow:

Comment: what you mean by " as follow"

Comment: Sorry, I was updating my post. I have updated my post with the mock-up webservice. [1] So I should invoke this method just before I return the value? (i.e. ForceDownload("C:\", "test"); return List<Locations>) [2] What value should I parse? virtualPath refers to the location of XML file, and fileName refers to the name of the file? [3] If I am right for point 2, does it mean that I have to save the contents of my List<Locations> before I invoke your method? --- I am sorry if I confused you with my comments, I boxed up the question numbers. (e.g. [1])

Comment: Do I need to add (using System.x)? Because I remember I was googling and I happen to see a solution similar to this. But when I added it to my codes, VS2010 did not recognise Response as a keyword.

Comment: Its hard to understand what's exactly I should explain . But If you want to generate file from this List<Locations> than yes you need to first generate the file from list and than call method ForceDownload . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx check this . Lines array is like your List .

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you very much, I apologise for all the inconvenience, because I am still rather new to all these programming, so I may not understand things as well :) I will test out the codes and see how it goes. :)

Comment: @user608576 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1424/discussion-between-joyce-and-user608576)